# T-SQL Stored Procedure error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'. Severity 15 PROCEDURE_1

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following Stored Procedure for SQL Server, which is not working.
I checked the order of begins and ends again and again, but I couldn't find the reason for the error.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.PROCEDURE_1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.PROCEDURE_1
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROCEDURE_1]
AS

    BEGIN

        DECLARE

        @number_of_active_members numeric(7)


        BEGIN TRY

            DECLARE
                count_active_members CURSOR LOCAL FOR
                 SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*), 1)
                 FROM TABLE_1 
                 WHERE MEMBER_STATUS = '1'

            OPEN count_active_members   

            FETCH count_active_members
                INTO @number_of_active_members

            CLOSE count_active_members

            DEALLOCATE count_active_members


            UPDATE TABLE_2
            SET NUMBER_FROM=0,NUMBER_TO = (@number_of_active_members / 5 )

        END TRY

    END

GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [`BEGIN TRY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) then you also *have* to have a `CATCH` block following it:

```
BEGIN TRY  
     { sql_statement | statement_block }  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
     [ { sql_statement | statement_block } ]  
END CATCH  
[ ; ]
```

It's unclear what you were trying to do with just a bare `TRY`, so it may be that the solution is to remove it entirely instead of adding the `CATCH`.

It's also unclear why you're writing laborious *procedural* code using cursors in a *set-based* language such as T-SQL, which can have an `UPDATE` referencing multiple tables as a single statement.